# Why does spelling matter?

Tags: meaning, orthography, language-evolution

If I write *mispelling* as supposed to *misspelling* why does it matter?  The meaning still exists.  Everyone knows what I meant to write.  There is no ambiguity.

Why do  some people consider the proper use so important?  Isn't language flexible?  Can't I use it as I wish?

I don't say these things to irritate or insult people, I'm saying them to convey meaning, meaning is achieved, so isn't the purpose of language in that instance satisfied?

Comment: Subjective and argumentative. Please read the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). Voting to close.

Comment: @Robusto I've always asked people this but come against a brick wall every time, where is a good place to get answers for this?  I've edited to try and phrase it less argumentatively.

Comment: Probably to make it easier to understand. How easy is this to read? "ive always askd ppl thiss but comeup agnst brik wall evrytym. Whr is a goood plase to get answrs fr this? ive editit to try and frase it less argumentatively".. heh, I didn't know how to ruin the last word:)

Comment: If you had a sub culture of youth who write like that and they all understand each other perfectly is that so bad?

Comment: Nope, I don't think there's anything wrong with that. I don't think I know anyone who goes around editing text and chat messages. I'm actually sorry I couldn't resist putting that comment there. I think this is argumentative and subjective too and would vote to close if I could. Good question for a drunk argument between a linguist and a grammarian, though.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: I have opinions on this matter, but I'm not going to give them here. This is not a proper question for this venue. You might try asking it over at Writers.SE.

Comment: Mark Twain might agree with you: [I don't see any use in having a uniform and arbitrary way of spelling words. We might as well make all clothes alike and cook all dishes alike.](http://www.twainquotes.com/Spelling.html) On the other hand, looking at his [plan for the improvement of English spelling](http://design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Twain_english.html), I think there is something to be said for a language where you, 20 years into the future, are still able to read what you wrote today ;)

Comment: @j-g thank you for that, the answer of survivability is a great point and one I've never considered.

Comment: Historically, the answer seems to be "because it makes it hard to read otherwise". Writing used to be phonetic, with some broad patterns - a small feline could be *cat, kat, katt, katte...* but not *qat* or *cad* or *xir* - but otherwise no real rules. This worked ok as long as the writer was considered more important than the reader. With the spread of printing and thus literacy, however, the convenience of the reader became more important, and thus spelling (slowly) became standardized.

Comment: I think my point is, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Generations of English speakers before you have wrestled with this question, and have come up with the current solution. It may not be optimal in a mathematical sense, but it is demonstrably workable, and history says it's *more* workable than what came before.

Comment: @Tragicomic - how about 'argmntvly'?

Comment: @HorusKol: Nice, that would work.. no, wait..

Comment: Sorry to prolong a discussion on a closed question but I passionately believe that the only purpose of the written word - aside from in a private diary - is for communication with the wider world. To do so on your terms and your terms alone is fundamentally selfish. We use common, standardised spelling and grammar not only for optimal comprehension but as a basic expression of respect for the reader. If you have genuine problems with achieving this then of course that is understandable but simply to eschew it altogether on a whim denigrates the practice, in my opinion. Unless you are a poet!

Answer (score 3):

That is because, in case you write **Red** in place of the word **Read** which is the past tense of the verb **to read** you are not conveying the meaning that you actually wish to convey.
This is one of the primary reasons for the emphasis on spelling of words.

Comment: Except that in your example the only way to know which pronunciation of "read" you mean, is context in which case the phonetic spelling "red" would be just as understandable... If I wrote "I red it in a book" you would never think "red" was the color in this context. (You don't think that when I say it anyway)

Comment: Inglish sirisli ni:d speling riform. Yu kud låwn såm letrs fråm ðe Aislændik ænd Nårwijn/Deinish ælfebet får ðe wawls ænd ðe kånsenents tu meik it mår fonetik, wi wudnt maind ;)